# Automatic line break for writing context-free grammars?

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking, grammar

I am currently writing context-free grammars in Latex, I have one production in each line, e.g.

```
S -> a | B
B -> C
C -> D | d
```

Currently I am using the math mode for this and a manual line break. Is there a better environment for my case? One where I e.g. don't need manual line breaks? Thanks :-)

Comment: Please add an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) so we know what you're using at the moment. For this particular case, I'd recommend the `amsmath` package and the `align` environment, so
`\begin{align} S &\to a \mid B \\ B &\to C \\ C &\to D \mid d \end{align}`.
I don't think you'll get around manual line breaks...
You also might want to use `align*` or an `aligned` environment inside of an `equation` environment, depending on your equation numbering needs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This looks like a job for the `listings` package, which not only will automatically do your line breaks, but will allow

- the `->` arrows to be rendered as proper TeX-ish arrows;
- unicode characters (*e.g.* greek characters) to be rendered by the TeX-ish mathematical equivalent;
- easy indentation and inline presentation of the grammatical rules;

and other aspects of control of the formatting.

**Example Source.**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
  basicstyle=\itshape,
  xleftmargin=3em,
  literate={->}{$\rightarrow$}{2}
           {α}{$\alpha$}{1}
           {δ}{$\delta$}{1}
}

\begin{document}
\noindent Example of a simple grammar:
\begin{lstlisting}
S -> α | B
B -> C
C -> D | δ
\end{lstlisting}
Note that the rules ``\lstinline{S -> α | B}\,'' and
``\lstinline{C -> D | δ}\,'' involve terminals.
\end{document}
```

The various ways in which the formatting is controlled above are as follows:

- The `basicstyle=\itshape` key indicates that the characters are to be typeset in italics, as is typical for a mathematics environment.
- The `xleftmargin=3em` describes a left indentation to apply for a "displayed" listing in the `lstlisting` environment.
- The `literate=...` instructions indicate that 'literate' ways to render various sequences of characters. For instance, the two characters `->` is with the corresponding arrow, and that for spacing purposes it should be given approximately two characters worth of horizontal space. (`listings` tries to give each character the same amount of space, even if you do not use a monospaced typeface; the default is about `0.6em`.) The other entries describes how to typeset the unicode greek characters.
- It is possible also to use these features inline, using the `\lstinline` macro.

**Result:**

[image: Sample CFG specification using lstlistings environment]

Comment: wow, that's great, thank you! Do you know how I can indent the complete lstlisting block? Is it possible to disable the justification on the | sign? Several | vertically don't look that good, as it's quite close to a line.

Comment: hmm and how would one write an \alpha in the lstlisting?

Comment: found the answers to my questions and edited Niel's post :-)

Comment: @stefan.at.wpf: if you want to avoid the almost-solid-line, you can increase the vertical spacing in the grammar using `basicstyle=\itshape\setstretch{1.3}` and the `setspace` package.

Comment: This is nice but it doesn't seem to address potential alignment needs, for example, it's common to have things like `| xxx` on the next line aligned with `\leftarrow` from previous lines.